# Шаблоны в Go - slice из неизвестного типа

Tags: ооп, golang

Здравствуйте. Начал изучать Go и начала интересовать такая тема: допустим, я хочу реализовать структуру данных (в коде она - некий `struct`) в которой будет храниться `slice`, тип элементов которого заранее неизвестен, и написать к ней методов, которые будут работать со срезом, тип элементов которого заранее неизвестен. Возможно ли это? Если, скажем, сделать срез из пустых интерфейсов. Если нет, то возможно ли решить такую штуку на Go?

Comment: Шаблонов в Go нет. Но кое-что можно реализовать через интерфейсы.

Comment: @GreenDragon это я знаю. Но можно ли реализовать конкретно данную штуку с использованием интерфейсов?

Comment: Можно. Посмотрите, например, как реализован стандартный пакет `sort`.

Comment: @GreenDragon мне нужна шаблонная структура данных, которая будет хранить неизвестного типа массив. С функциями все и так понятно.

Comment: Какая шаблонная структура данных вам нужна?

Comment: @GreenDragon скажем, некоторое множество, в котором поддерживается порядок элементов(при итерации по нему).

Comment: Возьмите что-то из готовых - [1](https://github.com/abishekk92/goset) или [2](https://github.com/deckarep/golang-set). Но для имитации множества в GO можно смело использовать `map[interface{}]bool`